# How to get date of first day three months ago from a date in sql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark

for Example there is a date '2021-08-21', I need to convert it to '2021-05-01'
I am confused with right functions to use as I want it to use it in Apache Spark SQL.

Comment: Perhaps replace 21 with 01 and then `SELECT add_months('2021-08-01', -3)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [add_month](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#add_months) first and then use [date_trunc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#date_trunc) to get the first day of the result of `add_month`.

```sql
select date_trunc('MONTH', add_months(date, -3))
```